# Use Mustache.js to render a list of values from a JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, mustache

I am using Mustache.js to format a response from a jQuery getJSON() request. The getJSON request gets a list of images names. I want to display a series of these images at the end of my existing content when the call is made.

The JSON that is returned looks like this:

```
[
  {"id":{"_time":1351063373,"_machine":56912161,"_inc":1690583039,"_new":false},"url":"5.jpg","tags":[]},
  {"id":{"_time":1351063237,"_machine":56912161,"_inc":1690583038,"_new":false},"url":"Repinzle-Logo.png", "tags":[]},
  {"id":{"_time":1351063186,"_machine":56912161,"_inc":1690583037,"_new":false},"url":"21.jpg","tags":[]}}
]
```

I am parsing it with the each function ... my AJAX request (with jQuery looks like this):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var imageNum=20;
    var imageCount=0;

    function getMoreImages(){
        imageCount=imageCount+imageNum;
        $.getJSON("/getImages", { start: imageNum, count: imageCount },
            function(data){
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                // do stuff with val.url

                var url = val.url;
                var template = $('#item-tpl').html();
                var newitem = Mustache.to_html(template, url);
                    $('#main').append(newitem);
                });     
              });
    }
</script>
```

And here is the mustache.js template

```
<script id="item-tpl" type="text/html">
    <div><img src="https://myurlstem.com/mydir/{{url}}" class="item"></div>
</script>
```

As far as I can see I've set everything up correctly, but for some reason `url` is not being sent to the template correctly.

Comment: Everything is working except the Url variable is never rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass an object to the `to_html` method.

```
var newitem = Mustache.to_html(template, { url: url });
```

Normally, I think you'd pass your entire model or collection.

Comment: Later I'll pass the whole list, I just want to get a simple version working. I think url and url might be conflicting, have changed the names.

Comment: Got some strange error not related to this question, will sort it out and report back.